# MATLAB Curve Fitting (Ellipse-like)

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I need to fit 10 data points (`x,y`) into this equation:

```
ay² + bxy + cx + dy + e = x²
```

It's told that this is a ellipse-like equation. I can't do it with usual curve fitting tools because it is not really a function (one `x` corresponds to 2 `y`s). I can't either use ellipse curve fitting because there is no `c*x` and `d*y` in an ellipse equation. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Both Oil and AK4749 gave right answer! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a linear system with variables [a b c d e]. You can use `\` to solve it:

```
 x=rand(10,1);
 y=rand(10,1);
 [y.^2,x.*y,x,y,ones(numel(x),1)]\x.^2

ans =

   -0.4437 %% a
    1.1034 %% b
    0.5337 %% c
   -0.2808 %% d
    0.0402 %% e
```

Comment: Hi I'm very curious does '\' use least square method in this case? You know, 10 equations with 5 unknowns.

Comment: @user1532230, yes it does use the min-square method. You can see the documentation there: http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3215-fitellipse