# Fitting an ellipse with no tilt on data

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, ellipse

I'd like to fit an ellipse with no tilt on my data.
This is the equation of an ellipse with no tilt:

```
a*x^2 + b*y^2 + c*x + d*y = e
```

I found this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12717181/3179989) interesting, but not sure how to change the parameters to get the solution to my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: here is the code I am using:

```
[y.^2,x,y,ones(numel(x),1)]\x.^2

ans =
1.0e+04 *
-0.0000
 0.0168
-0.0014
 3.6390
```

Comment: Your variables are `a` `b` `c` `d` and `e` you have observations `x` and `y` from which you can easily generate `x^2` and `y^2` and solve using least squares

Comment: Can you refer to any code or link as sample?

Comment: just follow the example in the thread you linked to

Comment: So I need to change x.*y to zeros(numel(x),1). is this right?

Comment: The question you linked to is a duplicate of your question. "not sure how to change the parameters" is not very specific. What have you actually tried and where is your code? Try writing our the two forms on pencil and paper. I'm sure that you can transform one to the other. Try a test case with know solution.

Comment: If you look at my equation again, it has no xy opposed to the equation that I linked to. xy is related to the tilt of the ellipse which in my case is zero. Now, I'd like to changed the solution into that link for my equation?

Comment: @M0HS3N just remove the `x*y` column from the matrix. But you should really put some code in your question (see [ask]).

Comment: @David - I added the code!!! I removed x*y column, however it does not return the correct solution. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does seem to work:

```
%// Creating some test data
x=sin(pi*(2*rand(50,1)-1))+(2*rand(size(x))-1)*.5;x=x./max(abs(x));
y=(sqrt(1-x.^2)+(2*rand(size(x))-1)*.5).*sign(rand(size(x))-0.5)+.5*x;

%// Setup Van der Monde matrices and solve equations
A=[y.^2,x.*y,x,y,ones(numel(x),1)]\x.^2
B=[y.^2,x,y,ones(numel(x),1)]\x.^2

plot(x,y,'o') %// Plot initial data
hold on
%// Plotting results the lazy way!
[X,Y]=meshgrid(1.5*(min([x;y]):.001:max([x;y])));
contour(X,Y,-X.^2+A(1)*Y.^2+A(2)*X.*Y+A(3)*X+A(4)*Y+A(5),[0 0],'b')
contour(X,Y,-X.^2+B(1)*Y.^2+B(2)*X+B(3)*Y+B(4),[0 0],'k')
hold off
```

The blue is the original ellipse and the black is the non-rotated ellipse

[image: Ellipses!]